# what nmcli command shows interfaces belonging to bridge

Tags: networkmanager, bridge

I've created bridge `br0` and added interfaces `eth0` and `eth1` to this bridge

```
nmcli con add ifname br0 type bridge con-name br0
nmcli con add type bridge-slave ifname eth0 master br0
nmcli con add type bridge-slave ifname eth1 master br0
nmcli con modify br0 bridge.stp no
nmcli con down eth0
nmcli con down eth1
nmcli con mod br0 ipv4.addresses "192.168.1.100/24"
nmcli con mod br0 ipv4.method manual
nmcli con down br0
nmcli con up br0
systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

After those steps my config looks like this

```
# nmcli dev status
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION
br-10            bridge    connected    br-10
br0              bridge    connected    br0
docker0          bridge    connected    docker0
eth0             ethernet  connected    bridge-slave-eth0
eth1             ethernet  connected    bridge-slave-eth1                
lo               loopback  unmanaged    --
wlan0            wifi      unmanaged    --
```

What `nmcli` command show interfaces assigned to given bridge? For `br0` it is clear because I've named connections `bridge-slave` but what about `br-10`? I'm asking especially for `nmcli` command because I've seen situation where bridge with 4 interfaces was created using `nmcli` but `brctl show` listed only 2 interfaces (those where cable were actually plugged) so I guess one should not rely on `brctl show` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following;

```
bridge link | grep master
```

Comment: `ip link show master br0` avoids the need to grep through the output.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nmcli device show`. The `-f` option lets you specify a comma-separated list of fields:

```
nmcli -f GENERAL.DEVICE,GENERAL.TYPE,BRIDGE.SLAVES device show bridge_device_name
```

(The only relevant field here is `BRIDGE.SLAVES`).

Not all fields are shown by default: the default value for the `-f` option is `common`. To see everything, use

```
nmcli -f all device show [device_name]
```